# get value of instance var controller method being tested

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, minitest

I have a method that essentially clones a record. Then redirects to the cloned records edit page. I have a mini test that needs to test that the record gets cloned and redirected to the new records edit path.

@new_record is a new object created in the controller method

```
  describe 'clone_record' do
    it 'should clone record' do
      @first_record = FactoryGirl.create(:blah)
      get :clone_record, :first_record_id => @first_record, :new_record => 'new_record'
      assert_redirected_to(edit_record_path(@new_record.id))
    end
  end
```

How do I get the value of @new_record in the test?

Comment: I don't see any question or issue in your post. What do you want from us?

Comment: Sorry, added a question.

Comment: in your test, since they are no concurrent HTTP requests and only one test at a time is being processed, you can use `new_record_id = first_record.id +1` unless you create more than one new record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the most recently created record Record.last should work.